Need help modifying modifying (training) code - CSRF remediation using state mismatch
Looking for some help with a training exercise which involves some coding to confirm that we understand a topic. Should be really simple, but sadly, the app we are using for this training uses a VERY rudimentary code editor/sandbox that doesn't provide ANY feedback other than a red/green result for any code changes/tests.
What I'm asking for is NOT "help with my homework", but simply help with the necessary code change to fix a CSRF exploit in a sample app by comparing the saved and current state values. The code is in Python which isn't really my strong suit, and I can't figure out exactly how it wants the code to be changed.
Here's the sample code, with my latest attempt commented.
import base64
import html
import json
import requests
import urllib


def encodeClientCredentials(clientId, clientSecret):
    s = urllib.parse.quote(clientId)+":" + urllib.parse.quote(clientSecret)
    return base64.b64encode(s.encode("utf-8"))


def clientCallback(query, clientData, authServerData, savedState):
    # Client
    # /GET /callback
    # query = {error, code, redirect_uri, state, scope, response_type }
    # savedState => Hash value saved by client after click "Approve"
    
    if "error" in query:
        return {
            "error": True,
            "msg": query["error"]
        }
    code = query["code"] if "code" in query else None
    # My code
    state = query["state"] if "state" in query else None
    # End of my Code
    form_data = {
        "grant_type": "authorization_code",
        "code": code,
        "redirect_uri": "http://client.com/callback"
    }
    encodedCredentials = encodeClientCredentials(
        clientData["client_id"],
        clientData["client_secret"]
    )
    encodedCredentials = encodedCredentials.decode("utf-8")
    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Authorization": "Basic " + encodedCredentials
    }
    r = requests.post(
        authServerData["tokenEndpoint"],
        data=form_data,
        headers=headers
    )

    tokRes = r.text
    # My code
    #if state <> savedState:
    #    return {
    #        "error": True,
    #        "msg": "State value mismatch",
    #        "statusCode": r.status_code
    #    }
    # End of my code

    if r.status_code >= 200 and r.status_code < 300:
        body = json.loads(tokRes)
        scope = body["scope"]
        access_token = body["access_token"]
        return {
            "error": False,
            "access_token": access_token,
            "scope": scope,
            "statusCode": r.status_code
        }
    else:
        body = json.loads(tokRes)
        return {
            "error": True,
            "msg": body["error"],
            "statusCode": r.status_code
        }


def getContactXSS(access_token=None):
    if not access_token:
        return {
            "error": True,
            "msg": "No Access Token",
            "statusCode": 401
        }
    else:
        headers = {
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token
        }
        r = requests.post(
            "http://protected:7012/contact-xss-get",
            headers=headers
        )
        rawResult = r.text
        if r.status_code >= 200 and r.status_code < 300:
            body = json.loads(rawResult)
            return {
                "error": False,
                "resource": body,
                "statusCode": r.status_code
            }
        else:
            return {
                "error": True,
                "statusCode": r.status_code,
            }


So, this version doesn't throw ANY error. It simple says the exploit has not been fixed. ANY help, pointers or working code would be HUGELY appreciated. I understand the concepts behind remediating CSRF exploits, I just need help getting the stupid sample working.


Your example doesn't run by itself - how have you been testing if the CSRF vulnerability was fixed? What fixes have you applied? Why do you think it should no longer be vulnerable? Asking homework questions is fine, but all the same rules apply, have a look here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions. Also, why is the part that appears to be part of your solution commented out and why is there no CSRF protection in getContactXSS?


I wasn't clear about that I guess. The application runs inside the tutorial application and only exposes the code that provides context for the changes they expect to be made.  They do not expose the entire app.


To clarify further. The code I provided (WITHOUT my highlighted code) runs in the lesson harness but includes the exploit in code not visible to me. The idea is to modify the code that IS provided to remediate the exploit.

First, you MUST check the state value before you make the request to the token endpoint, not after. Second, it seems there's quite a bit of information missing here especially regarding frontend code. CSRF is only ever a problem when you have cookies, I don't see anything related to cookies here. To prevent CSRF there are also multiple ways, the simplest being a custom header. For a XSS vulnerability you would need some frontend code where this could be injected. You don't seem to have a frontend here however.  Is there some frontend code you can access/ provide?

Please see my comment above this one. What I shared is ALL the lesson provides, which is the problem. The expectation is that, using only the code provided, I'm expected to mitigate the exploit.  I'll add a bit more info that I should have done initially - this is the "instructions" for the fix
The next comment will have the instructions:

"Let's take a look at the code and see if we can see if there is a way to remediate the vulnerability.
As you can see the saved state is a parameter to the callback function. Here's a python example:
def clientCallback(query, clientData, authServerData, savedState):
To remediate the CSRF we can check the state we receive from the callback URL against the save state.
If the state values do not match, the msg field of the response should be set to "State value mismatch".
After you fix the code you can perform the tests to see if the fix is correct."
